# Facing error while doing post in my react-redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have been struggling for past two days to implement a post request in my react-redux application. I can't understand if this is some problem with my syntax or the API. Attaching the relevant code below:

form

```
<form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <div>
                <label>Title: </label>
                <br />
                <input
                type="text"
                name="title"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={this.state.title}
                />
            </div>
            <br />
            <div>
                <label>Body: </label>
                <br />
                <textarea
                name="body"
                onChange={this.onChange}
                value={this.state.body}
                />
            </div>
            <br />
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

user.js (onchange and onsubmit events)

```
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

       const post = {
           title: this.state.title,
           body: this.state.body
        };

    this.props.createPost(post);
  }
```

store.js

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './reducers'

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(  postReducer, 
                            initialState, 
                            compose(
                            applyMiddleware(...middleware),
                            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() 
                         ));

export default store;
```

postReducer.js

```
const initialState = {
  item: {}
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case 'CREATE_POST':
        return {
          ...state,
          item: action.payload
        };
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

postAction.js

```
export const createPost = postData => dispatch => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(postData));
    fetch(URL, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'x-access-token': '*********'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postData)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(post =>
        dispatch({
          type: 'CREATE_POST',
          payload: post
        })
      );
  };
```

In my redux dev tools, I get a false response.
In my console, I see POST 400 Bad Request.

Note: I am doing post request on my localhost URL and checked the response on postman too, it works fine.

Below are the screenshot of redux dev tools window and postman response. Thanks.

[postman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oavkk.png)

[redux dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRPM2.png)

Comment: proceed with axios. Syntax-wise fetch #POSTlook fine.

Comment: Your form code to save the state looks good, and your createPost call looks right as well. Can you expand more on the error you're getting? Can you look at the network tab and see that it's what you expect?

Comment: your problem is "body: JSON.stringify(postData)" => you must past the form data not the json string

Comment: Thank you, people. Alex's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your content type is form-data you must pass the formData value not the JSON string.
So this line code `JSON.stringify(postData)` caused the 400 issue.

You can try like this

```
export const createPost = postData => dispatch => {


var form_data = new FormData();

for ( var key in postData ) {
    form_data.append(key, postData [key]);
}

fetch(URL, {
  method: 'post',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'x-access-token': '*********'
  },
  body: form_data
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(post =>
    dispatch({
      type: 'CREATE_POST',
      payload: post
    })
  );
```

};

I did not test the above code but I think it will work.
If you still want to send the JSON string data, you must change the content-type to application/json

Answer (score -1):

To make an API calls in a react-redux application you need to use sagas, https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/introduction/BeginnerTutorial.html, the usual flow is you need to dispatch an action which triggers a saga and then the saga gets the response and then saga can dispatch one more action to save it to the store.